# Install all dependencies for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, zlib

I can't understand how to install `freetype` and `libpng` libraries for `matplotlib` on Windows.

```
The C/C++ header for ... could not be found
```

The problem I get used to using `python setup.py install` in cmd.

Here I can't find such file. I tried just to copy a lib folder to site-packages but it didn't help.

Could you help me with steps to get it done ?

Comment: you may want to grab a binary version instead: see http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: @cel Ok. I went to your link, and then I wanted to install freetype. How ?

Answer (score 2):

You can download and install pre-built versions of matplotlib from [Christoph Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib). Download the `.whl` file that matches your Python interpreter (version; and 32 vs. 64 bit) and install it with pip, e.g.

```
pip install matplotlib-1.5.1-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

This should provide all the required dependencies of matplotlib (including freetype, and libpng).

Alternatively, you might like to take a look at [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which provides a version of Python with these difficult to build packages already included.